# Secret of the singing wall in Escape Lala 2

Tags: escape-lala-2

I have now completed Escape Lala 2 twice and received 100% of the Steam Achievements but I still don't understand the purpose of the singing wall with four mouths and nine eyes. Is it a hint for some puzzle or does it have some other purpose or meaning?